# Crear dataframe con el siguiente formato

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo un problema.

A través de pandas efectuó la lectura de un archivo excel, el cual me trae datos de consumo x, el tema de esto es que debo adaptar la lectura como se viene haciendo ahora, a una lectura lineal, actualmente la leo el archivo excel de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código python que ocupo para leer esos datos es este:

```
def get_utility_by_building_id_and_energy_type(self, building_ID, energy_type):
    # energy_type: 1 ~ electricity; 2 ~ fossil fuel
    df_temp = self.df_detail.loc[self.df_detail['building_ID'] == building_ID]
    df_temp = df_temp[['bill_start_dates', 'bill_end_dates', 'energy_type',
                       'energy_unit', 'energy_consumption', 'energy_cost']]
    if (energy_type == 1):
        df_temp = df_temp.loc[df_temp['energy_type'] == 'Electricity - Grid Purchased']
        if df_temp.empty: return None
    else:
        df_temp = df_temp.loc[df_temp['energy_type'] != 'Electricity - Grid Purchased']
        if df_temp.empty: return None

        '''
        Need to address how to combine multiple fossil fuel with different billing periods
        Current solution: proportionally allocate the by the number of days in each calendar month
        '''
    # Convert the energy unit to kwh
    df_temp.loc[df_temp['energy_unit'] == 'MJ', 'energy_consumption'] *= constants.Constants.MJ_to_kWh
    df_temp.loc[df_temp['energy_unit'] == 'GJ', 'energy_consumption'] *= constants.Constants.GJ_to_kWh
    df_temp.loc[df_temp['energy_unit'] == 'MWh', 'energy_consumption'] *= constants.Constants.MWH_to_kWh
    df_temp.loc[df_temp['energy_unit'] == 'Btu', 'energy_consumption'] *= constants.Constants.Btu_to_kWh
    df_temp.loc[df_temp['energy_unit'] == 'MMBtu', 'energy_consumption'] *= constants.Constants.MMBtu_to_kWh
    df_temp.loc[df_temp['energy_unit'] == 'Cubic Meters', 'energy_consumption'] *= constants.Constants.M3_to_kWh
    df_temp.loc[df_temp['energy_unit'] == 'Therms', 'energy_consumption'] *= constants.Constants.Therms_to_kWh
    df_temp.loc[df_temp['energy_unit'] == 'Decatherms', 'energy_consumption'] *= constants.Constants.Decatherms_to_kWh

    # Format the dataframe to match he raw utility data frame
    df_temp = df_temp[['bill_start_dates', 'bill_end_dates', 'energy_consumption', 'energy_cost']]
    df_temp.columns = ["Monthly Billing Start Date", "Monthly Billing End Date",
                       "kWh", "Cost"]
```

El problema surge ahora, que necesito leer los datos del excel de consumo de manera diferente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero manteniendo el formato de dataframe de arriba es decir, necesito generar una entrada así:

```
df_temp = df_temp[['bill_start_dates', 'bill_end_dates', 'energy_type',
                       'energy_unit', 'energy_consumption', 'energy_cost']]
```

Donde bill_start_dates y bill_end_dates se los paso de manera manual y el consumo es lo unico que leo dentro del excel, donde Elec_Y717m01 corresponde a enero y asi sucesivamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si entendí bien tu problema, se me ocurre una solución que igual es medio sucia y no óptima, pero funciona (supón que ya tienes todos los imports):

Como me dio flojera replicar tus datos, cree un DataFrame con datos aleatorios, pero en la forma del segundo Excel:

```
monthly_readings=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(1,12)),columns=["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", 
                                                                            "APR", "MAY", "JUN",
                                                                            "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", 
                                                                            "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"])
```

Esto genera un dataframe de un solo renglón con 12 columnas, una por mes, como indicas en tu problema.

Lo siguiente es iterar sobre los valores de ese renglón:

```
a = np.array(monthly_readings.loc[0])
for n in a:
    df_temp = df_temp.append({'energy_consumption': n}, ignore_index=True)
```

Dices que tienes los demás datos, aparte del consumo. Pues habría que ponerlos en el diccionario que se pasa al `append()` del `df_temp`. Tal como está, te va a crear un registro nuevo en el dataframe, pero con todas las columnas, excepto `energy_consumption` con NaN. Obvio, si el dataframe de consumo trae varios registros, pues iteras sobre los registros.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono, saludos!

Comment: Que bueno, ya sin ningún error, me imagino. ¡Saludos!